# How to put 2 different arrays inside different columns of a listview

Tags: arrays, powershell, listview

I'm trying to create a listview with 2 separate columns.  The first column should show a list of folder names.  The second column should show the last modified date of a specific file within the folders.

Array 1 = list of folders
Array 2 = date modified of a file within the list of folders

I'm able to create the arrays and list out the folder names, however I am having problems populating the second column with the date modified of the file within the folder.  The "echo $filedate.lastwritetime" correctly shows all of the last modfied dates however when I try to display it in the ListView column, only 1 date is shown for all rows.

```cs
$path = C:\Test\

$folders = Get-ChildItem $path

foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    $filedate = Get-ChildItem -Path $path\$folder\"Last Backed Up.txt"
    echo $filedate.LastWriteTime
}

[void]$listView.Columns.Add("Folder Name", 150);
[void]$listView.Columns.Add("Last Modified Date", 150);

$folders | ForEach-Object {
    $row = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.Name)   
    [void]$row.SubItems.Add($filedate.LastWriteTime.Tostring())
    [void]$listView.Items.Add($row)
}

$form.Controls.Add($listview)

$form.Topmost = $true

$result = $form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: I think $filedate only contains the `LastWriteTime` of the last folder, I don't see the `LastWriteTime`s being added to an array

Comment: This is the array for the LastWriteTime

    foreach ($folder in $folders) {
        $filedate = Get-ChildItem -path $path\$folder\"Last Backed Up.txt"
        echo $filedate.lastwritetime
    }

echo correctly shows all the different modifed dates, it just doesn't show up in the listview

Comment: The array contains all values, when I do echo $filedate.lastwritetime, multiple values show up, I just can't get it to show in the listview.

Comment: `echo` is an alias for `Write-Output`. You are outputting `$filedate.lastwritetime` on every iteration with `echo`. Also during each iteration, `$filedate` ***is being overwritten*** based on `$folder`. Once the loop completes, `$filedate` only has the ***one item*** in it, the last `$folder` based file searched. That is what you are adding later to `$listview`. Consolidate loop activity within the first `foreach` loop and remove the `foreach-object`. If you want to work with arrays, then keep two loops. If you are expecting to add each file date individually, then stick to one loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to have two arrays and iterate through the `$folders` array twice.
This can be done in one loop.

Since it is unsure all folders actually DO contain a file called `Last Backed Up.txt`, I suggest you do the following. The interesting part for you is the `$folders | ForEach-Object {..}` loop, because you already have the form ready. For clarity however the code complete:

```
$path = 'C:\Test'

# get an array of subfolder objects in the root folder $path
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory  # should we add -Recurse to also dig into any subfolder?

# build your form
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = "Backup Folders"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,400) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form.TopMost = $true

$listView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$listView.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
$listView.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(560,280) 
$listView.Anchor = 'Top,Right,Bottom,Left'
$listView.View = 'Details'
$listView.FullRowSelect = $true
$listView.GridLines = $true

# add two columns to the listView
[void]$listView.Columns.Add("Folder Name", 150)
[void]$listView.Columns.Add("Last Modified Date", 150)

# iterate through the list of folders 
$folders | ForEach-Object {
    # try to get the LastWriteTime of the file 'Last Backed Up.txt' inside this folder
    $file = Get-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath 'Last Backed Up.txt') -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($file) { $date = $file.LastWriteTime.Tostring() } else { $date = '' }

    # create a new row for the listview
    $row = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem( $_.Name )     # first colum:  the folder name
    [void]$row.SubItems.Add($date)                                     # second colum: the file LastWriteTime
    [void]$listView.Items.Add($row)
}

$form.Controls.Add($listview)

# add an event handler on the listbox to do something with the selected item
$listView.Add_Click({
    # here put your code to perform some action with the selected subfolder
    $selected = $listView.SelectedItems[0].Text
    $lastModified = $listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text
    # for demo, simply show a messagebox
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($lastModified)) {
        $message = "Subfolder '$selected' was never backed up"
    }
    else {
        $message = "Subfolder '$selected' was last backed up on $lastModified"
    }
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($message, "Backup")
})

[void]$form.ShowDialog()

# we're done, so remove the form from memory
$form.Dispose()
```

<sup>P.S. The fact that in your code only 1 date is shown for all rows, is because you are resetting variable `$filedate` on every iteration in your first loop. Therefore, only the last file is captured in the variable.</sup>

---

**Update**

---

Because you want to be able to sort the items in the listview as you have commented, I have updated the code as follows.

It now responds to clicks on the column headers to dynamically sort.
Initially, the listview shows items sorted Ascending on the '**Folder Name**' column.
If you click on the '**Last Modified Date**' column header, it will sort the items by the dates displayed. Clicking the same column header again will toggle the sort from Ascending to Descending and vice versa.

```
$path = 'C:\Test'

# get an array of subfolder objects in the root folder $path
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory  # should we add -Recurse to also dig into any subfolder?

# build your form
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = "Backup Folders"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,400) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form.TopMost = $true

$listView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$listView.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
$listView.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(560,280) 
$listView.Anchor = 'Top,Right,Bottom,Left'
$listView.View = 'Details'
$listView.FullRowSelect = $true
$listView.GridLines = $true
$listView.Sorting = [System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder]::None  # IMPORTANT

# add two columns to the listView
[void]$listView.Columns.Add("Folder Name", 150)
[void]$listView.Columns.Add("Last Modified Date", 150)

# iterate through the list of folders initially sort the items by FolderName (column 1) ascending
# $items will be an array of objects to help sorting whatever is displayed in the listview
$items = $folders | ForEach-Object {
    # try to get the LastWriteTime of the file 'Last Backed Up.txt' inside this folder
    $file = Get-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath 'Last Backed Up.txt') -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    # emit an object to be collected in the $items array
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'FolderName' = $_.Name
        'Modified'   = if ($file) { $file.LastWriteTime }  # a real DateTime object here for accurate sorting
    }
} | Sort-Object FolderName

# create three script-scoped variables to keep score of the current sort
$script:sortColumn     = 0
$script:sortDescending = $false
$script:sortProperty   = @('FolderName', 'Modified')[$script:sortColumn]

# fill the listview for the first time
$items | ForEach-Object {
    # create a new row for the listview
    $row = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem( $_.FolderName )     # first colum:  the folder name
    if ($_.Modified) { [void]$row.SubItems.Add($_.Modified.ToString()) }     # second colum: the file LastWriteTime
    [void]$listView.Items.Add($row)
}

# add an event handler for when the user clicks on one of the column headers
$listView.Add_ColumnClick({
    param($sender, $e)  # $sender is the listview itself, $e is ColumnClickEventArgs
    if ($e.Column -eq $script:sortColumn) {
        # click on the currently sorted column --> reverse sort
        $script:sortDescending = $script:sortDescending -xor $true
    }
    else {
        $script:sortColumn     = $e.Column
        $script:sortDescending = $false
        $script:sortProperty   = @('FolderName', 'Modified')[$script:sortColumn]
    }

    # now sort the $items array on property $script:sortProperty in the 
    $temp = $items | Sort-Object $script:sortProperty -Descending:$script:sortDescending
    # redraw the listview items
    # using SuspendLayout() method before and ResumeLayout() after adding the items increases the performance
    $listView.SuspendLayout()
    $listView.Items.Clear()
    $temp | ForEach-Object {
        # create a new row for the listview
        $row = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem( $_.FolderName )     # first colum:  the folder name
        if ($_.Modified) { [void]$row.SubItems.Add($_.Modified.ToString()) }     # second colum: the file LastWriteTime
        [void]$listView.Items.Add($row)
    }
    $listView.ResumeLayout()
    $temp = $null
})

# add an event handler on the listbox to do something with the selected item
$listView.Add_Click({
    # here put your code to perform some action with the selected subfolder
    $selected = $listView.SelectedItems[0].Text
    $lastModified = $listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text
    # for demo, simply show a messagebox
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($lastModified)) {
        $message = "Subfolder '$selected' was never backed up"
    }
    else {
        $message = "Subfolder '$selected' was last backed up on $lastModified"
    }
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($message, "Backup")
})

$form.Controls.Add($listview)

[void]$form.ShowDialog()

# we're done, so remove the form from memory
$form.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks Theo! If I add this line $listView.Sorting = 'Descending' it sorts by the first column, however I want to sort by the Modified date.  I tried adding it here as well
$file = Get-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath 'Last Backed Up.txt') | sort-object -descending lastwritetime
But that doesn't seem to work either any idea how to sort based on the modified date column?

Comment: @MP I have updated my answer and added new code where it now is possible to choose the sorting by clicking the column headers. Enjoy!